# ctypes variable length structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Ever since I read Dave Beazley's post on binary I/O handling (http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2009/08/python-binary-io-handling.html) I've wanted to create a Python library for a certain wire protocol. However, I can't find the best solution for variable length structures. Here's what I want to do:

```
import ctypes as c

class Point(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x',c.c_double),
        ('y',c.c_double),
        ('z',c.c_double)
        ]

class Points(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('num_points', c.c_uint32),
        ('points', Point*num_points) # num_points not yet defined!
        ]
```

The class `Points` won't work since `num_points` isn't defined yet. I could redefine the `_fields_` variable later once `num_points` is known, but since it's a class variable it would effect all of the other `Points` instances.

What is a pythonic solution to this problem?

Comment: Why do you need a structure? Can't you just send the buffer?

Comment: Can I ask what the C `struct` looks like? I'm assuming `struct { size_t num_points; Point poits[]; }` but I might be wrong (especially if your C code uses pre-C99 hacks to achieve flexible array member behavior).

Comment: There's no single C struct equivalent. One would need to build up a buffer and then send it.

Comment: The struct definition given by @ChrisLutz actually would work, providing you created a pointer to it by malloc(sizeof(struct whatever)+bytes_used_by_array).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most straightforward way, with the example you gave is to define the structure just when you have the information you need.

A simple way of doing that is creating the class at the point you will use it, not at module root - you can, for example, just put the `class` body inside a function, that will act as a factory - I think that is the most readable way.

```
import ctypes as c



class Point(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x',c.c_double),
        ('y',c.c_double),
        ('z',c.c_double)
        ]

def points_factory(num_points):
    class Points(c.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('num_points', c.c_uint32),
            ('points', Point*num_points) 
            ]
    return Points

#and when you need it in the code:
Points = points_factory(5)
```

Sorry -
It is the C code that will "fill in" the values for you - that is not the answer them. WIll post another way.

Comment: As you noted at the end this won't work for receiving data into. It made me think of another possible solution though where the class returns an inner class of the proper size.

Answer (score 3):

And now, for something completly different -
If all you need is dealing with the Data, possibly the "most Pythonic" way is not trying to use ctypes to handle raw data in memory at all.

This approach just uses struct.pack and .unpack to serialiase/unserialize teh data as it moves on/off the your app. The "Points" class can accept the raw bytes, and creates python objects from that, and can serialize the data trough a "get_data" method. Otherwise, it is just am ordinary python list.

```
import struct

class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0.0, y=0.0, z= 0.0):
        self.x, self.y, self.z = x,y,z
    def get_data(self):
        return struct.pack("ddd", self.x, self.y, self.z)


class Points(list):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            return
        pointsize = struct.calcsize("ddd")
        for index in xrange(struct.calcsize("i"), len(data) - struct.calcsize("i"), pointsize):
            point_data = struct.unpack("ddd", data[index: index + pointsize])
            self.append(Point(*point_data))

    def get_data(self):
        return struct.pack("i", len(self)) + "".join(p.get_data() for p in self)
```

Comment: The benefit to using Beazley's method is I don't have to calculate sizes and pack/unpack the data.

Answer (score 3):

This question is really, really, old:

I have a simpler answer, which seems strange, but avoids metaclasses and resolves the issue that ctypes doesn't allow me to directly build a struct with the same definition as I can in C.

The example C struct, coming from the kernel:

```
struct some_struct {
        __u32   static;
        __u64   another_static;
        __u32   len;
        __u8    data[0];
};
```

With ctypes implementation:

```
import ctypes
import copy

class StructureVariableSized(ctypes.Structure):
    _variable_sized_ = []

    def __new__(self, variable_sized=(), **kwargs):
        def name_builder(name, variable_sized):
            for variable_sized_field_name, variable_size in variable_sized:
                name += variable_sized_field_name.title() + '[{0}]'.format(variable_size)
            return name

        local_fields = copy.deepcopy(self._fields_)
        for matching_field_name, matching_type in self._variable_sized_:
            match_type = None
            for variable_sized_field_name, variable_size in variable_sized:
                if variable_sized_field_name == matching_field_name:
                    match_type = matching_type
                    break
            if match_type is None:
                raise Exception
            local_fields.append((variable_sized_field_name, match_type*variable_size))
        name = name_builder(self.__name__, variable_sized)
        class BaseCtypesStruct(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_ = local_fields
            _variable_sized_ = self._variable_sized_
        classdef = BaseCtypesStruct
        classdef.__name__ = name
        return BaseCtypesStruct(**kwargs)


class StructwithVariableArrayLength(StructureVariableSized):
    _fields_ = [
        ('static', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ('another_static', ctypes.c_uint64),
        ('len', ctypes.c_uint32),
        ]
    _variable_sized_ = [
        ('data', ctypes.c_uint8)
    ]

struct_map = {
    1: StructwithVariableArrayLength
}
sval32 = struct_map[1](variable_sized=(('data', 32),),)
print sval32
print sval32.data
sval128 = struct_map[1](variable_sized=(('data', 128),),)
print sval128
print sval128.data
```

With sample output:

```
machine:~ user$ python svs.py 
<__main__.StructwithVariableArrayLengthData[32] object at 0x10dae07a0>
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_32 object at 0x10dae0830>
<__main__.StructwithVariableArrayLengthData[128] object at 0x10dae0830>
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_128 object at 0x10dae08c0>
```

This answer works for me for a couple reasons:

1. The argument to the constructor can be pickled, and has no references to types.
2. I define all of the structure inside of the StructwithVariableArrayLength definition.
3. To the caller, the structure looks identical as if I had just defined the array inside of _fields_
4. I have no ability to modify the underlying structure defined in the header file, and accomplish my goals without changing any underlying code.
5. I don't have to modify any parse/pack logic, this only does what I'm trying to do which is build a class definition with a variable length array.
6. This is a generic, reusable container that be sent into the factory like my other structures.

I would obviously prefer the header file took a pointer, but that isn't always possible. That answer was frustrating. The others were very tailored to the data structure itself, or required modification of the caller.

Comment: Love this answer, but I'm confused by the ```matching_location``` variable.
Where is this 3rd value coming from while iterating over ```self._variable_sized_``` ??
In order for the variable field to be added at the end of the list, on first iteration this should equate to "3", no? Where is the 3 coming from considering ```location``` is initialized with ```None```?

Comment: You're correct, the interpreter says `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack` right there. The final version of this (kinda as hinted by your question) omits location information, and does a `local_fields.append((variable_sized_field_name, match_type*variable_size))`. That also meant it needed to invert the ordering, by looping through _variable_sized_ in the outer loop, to get append order the same as definition order.

Answer (score 2):

So, just as in C, you can't do exactly what you do want.
The only useful way of working with a structure that does what you want in C is to have it as

```c
struct Points {
   int num_points;
   Point *points;
}
```

And have utility code to alloc you memory where you can put your data.
Unless you have some safe maxsize, and don't want to bother with that part of the code
(memory allocation) - the network part of the code would then transmit just the needed
data from within the structure, not the whole of it.

To work with Python ctypes with a structure member which actually contains a pointer to where your data is (and so, may be of variable length) - you will also have to alloc and free memory manually (if you are filling it on the python side) - or just read the data - f creating and destroying the data is done on native code functions.

The structure creating code can be thus:

```
import ctypes as c



class Point(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x',c.c_double),
        ('y',c.c_double),
        ('z',c.c_double)
        ]

class Points(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('num_points', c.c_uint32),
        ('points', c.POINTER(Point))
        ]
```

And the code to manage the creation and deletion of these data structures can be:

```
__all_buffers = {}
def make_points(num_points):
   data = Points()
   data.num_points = num_points
   buf = c.create_string_buffer(c.sizeof(Point) * num_points)
   __all_buffers[c.addressof(buf)] = buf
   p = Point.from_address(c.addressof(buf))
   data.points = c.pointer(p)
   return data

def del_points(points):
    del __all_buffers[c.addressof(m.points[0])
    points.num_points = 0
```

The use f the global  variable "__all_buffers"  keep a reference to the
python-created buffer object so that python does not destroy it upon
leaving the make_points structure. An alternative to this is to get a reference to
either libc (on unixes) or winapi,and call system's `malloc` and `free`functions  yourself

OR - you can just go with plain old "struct" Python module, instead of using ctypes -
doubly so if you will have no C code at all, and are just using ctypes for the
"structs"  convenience.

Comment: This is how I could do it in C code. I was hoping for a way to take advantage of the dynamic nature of Python. You're answers are great though and covered the spectrum of possible solutions!

Answer (score 2):

You could use ctypes pointers to do this.

**C struct**

```
struct some_struct {
    uint  length;
    uchar data[1];
};
```

**Python code**

```
from ctypes import *

class SomeStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('length', c_uint), ('data', c_ubyte)]

#read data into SomeStruct
s = SomeStruct()
ptr_data = pointer(s.data)
for i in range(s.length):
    print ptr_data[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've come up with so far (still a little rough):

```
import ctypes as c

MAX_PACKET_SIZE = 8*1024
MAX_SIZE = 10

class Points(c.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('_buffer', c.c_byte*MAX_PACKET_SIZE)
    ]
    _inner_fields = [
        ('num_points', c.c_uint32),
        ('points', 'Point*self.num_points')
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.num_points = 0
        self.points = [0,]*MAX_SIZE

    def parse(self):
        fields = []
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            if type(ctype) == str:
                ctype = eval(ctype)
            fields.append((name, ctype))
            class Inner(c.Structure, PrettyPrinter):
                _fields_ = fields
            inner = Inner.from_address(c.addressof(self._buffer))
            setattr(self, name, getattr(inner, name))
        self = inner
        return self

    def pack(self):
        fields = []
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            if type(ctype) == str:
                ctype = eval(ctype)
            fields.append((name, ctype))
        class Inner(c.Structure, PrettyPrinter):
            _fields_ = fields
        inner = Inner()
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            value = getattr(self, name)
            if type(value) == list:
                l = getattr(inner, name)
                for i in range(len(l)):
                    l[i] = getattr(self, name)[i]
            else:
                setattr(inner, name, value)
        return inner
```

The methods `parse` and `pack` are generic, so they could be moved to a metaclass. This would make it's use almost as easy as the snippet I first posted.

Comments on this solution? Still looking for something simpler, not sure if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to consider a third-party package, you might be able to use [Construct](https://construct.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Let's take the structure you've provided:

```py
import ctypes

class CPoint(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('x',ctypes.c_double),
        ('y',ctypes.c_double),
        ('z',ctypes.c_double)
    ]
```

Using Construct's syntax, we would define the equivalent as follows:

```py
import construct

Point = construct.Struct(
    "x" / construct.Float64l,
    "y" / construct.Float64l,
    "z" / construct.Float64l
)
```

We can check that they are the same:

```py
>>> point_coordinates = {"x": 3.14, "y": 2.71, "z": 1.41}
>>> c_point = CPoint(**point_coordinates)
>>> point = Point.build(point_coordinates)
>>> bytes(c_point) == bytes(point)
True
```

Now we define the `Points` structure according to the Construct syntax:

```py
Points = construct.Struct(
    "num_points" / construct.Int32ul,
    "points" / construct.Array(construct.this.num_points, Point)
)
```

Construct will automatically create an array of `points` based on `num_points`.

We can serialize a `Points` structure:

```py
>>> Points.build({"num_points": 2, "points": [{"x": 3.14, "y": 2.71, "z": 1.41}, {"x": 1.73, "y": 1.20, "z": 1.61}]})
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\t@\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xae\x05@\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\x8f\xf6?\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xae\xfb?333333\xf3?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf9?'
```

Or de-serialize it:

```py
>>> res = Points.parse(b'\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x85\xebQ\xb8\x1e\t@\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xae\x05@\x8f\xc2\xf5(\\\x8f\xf6?\xaeG\xe1z\x14\xae\xfb?333333\xf3?\xc3\xf5(\\\x8f\xc2\xf9?')
>>> print(res)
Container:
    num_points = 2
    points = ListContainer:
        Container:
            x = 3.14
            y = 2.71
            z = 1.41
        Container:
            x = 1.73
            y = 1.2
            z = 1.61
```

And of course access the structure fields:

```py
>>> for i in range(res.num_points):
...     print(res.points[i].x)
...
3.14
1.73
```