# metaclass conflict with ctypes Structure

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm trying to create a metaclass for the class I created here: [ctypes variable length structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015487/ctypes-variable-length-structures/7032972#7032972)

I want to simplify the Points class so it looks like this (Python 3.2):

```
class Points(c.Structure, metaclass=VariableMeta):
    _fields_ = [
        ('num_points', c.c_uint32),
        ('points', 'Point*self.num_points')
    ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.num_points = 0
        self.points = [0,]*MAX_SIZE
```

This is the metaclass I have so far:

```
class VariableMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        dct['_inner_fields'] = dct['_fields_']
        dct['_fields_'] = [('_buffer', c.c_byte*MAX_PACKET_SIZE)]
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def parse(self):
        fields = []
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            if type(ctype) == str:
                ctype = eval(ctype)
            fields.append((name, ctype))
            class Inner(c.Structure, PrettyPrinter):
                _fields_ = fields
            inner = Inner.from_address(c.addressof(self._buffer))
            setattr(self, name, getattr(inner, name))
        self = inner
        return self

    def pack(self):
        fields = []
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            if type(ctype) == str:
                ctype = eval(ctype)
            fields.append((name, ctype))
        class Inner(c.Structure, PrettyPrinter):
            _fields_ = fields
        inner = Inner()
        for name, ctype in self._inner_fields:
            value = getattr(self, name)
            if type(value) == list:
                l = getattr(inner, name)
                for i in range(len(l)):
                    l[i] = getattr(self, name)[i]
            else:
                setattr(inner, name, value)
        return inner
```

It looks like it should work, but when I run it I get the error: `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`.

I searched for hints to the solution of this problem, but ctypes Structure looks to be implemented in a c library. I am not sure how to fix this, any help or the specific solution is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `ctypes.Structure` uses its own custom metaclass: `_ctypes.StructType`.  Since you inherit the metaclass from *Structure*, Python does not know which metaclass to use when constructing your class.

You can fix this by inheriting your metaclass from `_ctypes.StructType`.  Since the name of the metaclass is an implementation detail of the *ctypes* module, I recommend writing `type(ctypes.Structure)` to get the metaclass dynamically.

```
import ctypes

class VariableMeta(type(ctypes.Structure)):
    pass
```

The drawback with this approach is that you limit the use of your metaclass.  This might be OK if you only plan to use it for subclasses of `ctypes.Structure`.

Another approach is to create a intermediate metaclass that inherits from both metaclasses.

```
class PointsMetaClass(type(ctypes.Structure), VariableMeta):
    pass

class Points(c.Structure, metaclass=PointsMetaClass):
    # ...
```

Always make sure that you use `super()` instead of hard-coding `type` in your metaclass' `__new__`!

```
return super(VariableMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
```

As Guido once wrote: Writing metaclasses in Python [will cause your head to explode](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/metaclasses/)!