# Python crashes on field access ctypes

Tags: winapi, ctypes, python-3.5

I'm using the ctypes module to call `GetTcpTable2`.
I've been slowly converting the example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb485772(v=vs.85).aspx) in C++ to Python; but am getting crash during a field access.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ptcp_table = POINTER(MIB_TCPTABLE2)()
    ptcp_table = cast(create_string_buffer(sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE2)),
                      POINTER(MIB_TCPTABLE2))
    ip_addr = in_addr()
    size = c_ulong(sizeof(MIB_TCPTABLE2))
    retval = GetTcpTable2(ptcp_table, byref(size), TRUE)
    if retval == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
        ptcp_table = cast(create_string_buffer(size.value),
                          POINTER(MIB_TCPTABLE2))
        if not ptcp_table:
            #throw error
            pass

    retval = GetTcpTable2(ptcp_table, byref(size), TRUE)
    if retval == NO_ERROR:
        print("Entries %d" % ptcp_table[0].dwNumEntries)
        for i in range(0, ptcp_table[0].dwNumEntries):
            print(ptcp_table[0].table[i])
            #ip_addr.S_un.S_addr = ptcp_table[0].table[i].dwLocalAddr
            #ip_addr_string = inet_nota(ip_addr)
            #print(ip_addr_string)
            #print(string_at(ip_addr_string))
```

It crashes when trying to access `dwLocalAddr` apart of `table[i]`.

```
ptcp_table[0].table[i].dwLocalAddr
```

However it doesn't crash when just printing `ptcp_table[0].table[i]`.
I've tried printing and accessing other fields; but Python just crashes.

Here are my struct definitions:

```
class MIB_TCPROW2(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwState", c_ulong),
        ("dwLocalAddr", c_ulong),
        ("dwLocalPort", c_ulong),
        ("dwRemoteAddr", c_ulong),
        ("dwRemotePort", c_ulong),
        ("dwOwningPid", c_ulong),
        ("dwOffloadState", c_int)
    ]


class MIB_TCPTABLE2(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwNumEntries", c_ulong),
        ("table", POINTER(MIB_TCPROW2))
    ]
```

Definition of `GetTcpTable2`:

```
GetTcpTable2 = windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2
GetTcpTable2.argtypes = [POINTER(MIB_TCPTABLE2), POINTER(c_ulong), c_char]
GetTcpTable2.restype = c_ulong
```

I have a small hunch that in the definition of the `MIB_TCPTABLE2` struct; the documentation says that `table` is an array of `MIB_TCPROW2` size `ANY_SIZE`; and further inspection is that `ANY_SIZE` is 1 from checking the `iphlpapi.h` file. And I know that the size of `POINTER(MIB_TCPROW2)` doesn't equal the size of `MIB_TCPROW2`.

Comment: `MIB_TCPTABLE2` is a variable-sized structure; `dwNumEntries` tells you how big the `table` array actually is. How you represent that to Python I have no idea though.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you for pointing this out. I've done a bit more searching and looked about creating a class factory method for `MIB_TCPTABLE2` to generate variable lengthed versions of it.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala Have to wait 2 days before I can do that. (3 hours from now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into other ctypes questions revolving around variable length fields inside of a struct, and came to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016078/249552) which suggested to use a factory method to generate the class definitions.

```
def MIB_TCPTABLE2_FACTORY(size):
    class MIB_TCPTABLE2(Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("dwNumEntries", c_ulong),
            ("table", MIB_TCPROW2 * size)
        ]
    return MIB_TCPTABLE2
```

I can use this knowing the `size` returned from `GetTcpTable2` to create a new type. And then all I have to do is change the `argtypes` of `GetTcpTable2` to accept a `void *`.

```
GetTcpTable2.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_ulong), c_char]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.  I first got the required size by passing in the following arguments:

```
ret = windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2(None, byref(tcp_table_size), True)
```

Notice None is the first argument, which is equivalent to NULL when passing it into ctypes windows function.  Then I defined the MIB_TCPTABLE2 class and inside it, I passed in the size returned by the first call to GetTcpTable2:

```
class MIB_TCPTABLE2(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwNumEntries", c_ulong),
        ("table", MIB_TCPROW2 * tcp_table_size.value),
    ]
```

Next, I created an instance of the structure and called GetTcpTable2 again passing in the newly created structure:

```
tcp_table = MIB_TCPTABL2()

ret = windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2(byref(tcp_table), byref(tcp_table_size), True)
```

Here's the sample code:

```
from ctypes import *
import socket
import struct

NO_ERROR = 0
ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122

TcpConnectionOffloadStateInHost = 0
TcpConnectionOffloadStateOffloading = 1
TcpConnectionOffloadStateOffloaded = 2
TcpConnectionOffloadStateUploading = 3
TcpConnectionOffloadStateMax = 4

class MIB_TCPROW2(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dwState", c_ulong),
        ("dwLocalAddr", c_ulong),
        ("dwLocalPort", c_ulong),
        ("dwRemoteAddr", c_ulong),
        ("dwRemotePort", c_ulong),
        ("dwOwningPid", c_ulong),
        ("dwOffloadState", c_ulong),
    ]
    
def main():
    windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_ulong), c_bool]
    tcp_table_size = c_ulong()
        
    ret = windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2(None, byref(tcp_table_size), True)
    if ret == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
        class MIB_TCPTABLE2(Structure):
            _fields_ = [
                ("dwNumEntries", c_ulong),
                ("table", MIB_TCPROW2 * tcp_table_size.value),
            ]
        
        tcp_table = MIB_TCPTABLE2()
        
        ret = windll.iphlpapi.GetTcpTable2(byref(tcp_table), byref(tcp_table_size), True)
        if ret != NO_ERROR:
            print("ERROR: GetTcpTable2() failed, error = " + str(ret))
        else:
            for i in range(tcp_table.dwNumEntries):
                dest_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('<L', tcp_table.table[i].dwRemoteAddr))
                print("PID: " + str(tcp_table.table[i].dwOwningPid) + ", DEST IP: " + dest_ip)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```